# how to get HTML Inputs deep array

Tags: html, forms

How do you create a few array elements to contain deeper parameters?
I got for example:

```
<input name="product[name]" />
<input name="product[quantity]" />
```

And i wanna get output in post like

```
[product] => Array ( 
  [product] => Array ( [name] => x, [quantity] => x ) 
  [product] => Array ( [name] => x, [quantity] => x ) 
)
```

any idea ?  i tried to do like that

```
<input name="product[][name]" />
<input name="product[][quantity]" />    
<input name="product[][name]" />
<input name="product[][quantity]" />
```

and also:

```
<input name="product[name][]" />
<input name="product[quantity][]" />
<input name="product[name][]" />
<input name="product[quantity][]" />
```

But got many arrays of singles inputs or only one group of arrays posting.

---

output #1 for settings like: product[][name]

```
product 
[▼
  [▼
    "position" => "1"
  ]
  [▼
    "name" => "qwe"
  ]
  [▼
    "quantity" => "1"
  ]
  [▼
    "singlePriceNetto" => "123"
  ]
  [▼
    "singlePriceSummaryNetto" => "123,00"
  ]
  [▼
    "singleVat" => "23"
  ]
  [▼
    "singleVatSummary" => "28,29"
  ]
  [▼
    "singleSummaryBrutto" => "151,29"
  ]
  [▼
    "position" => "2"
  ]
  [▼
    "name" => "321"
  ]
  [▼
    "quantity" => "1"
  ]
  [▼
    "singlePriceNetto" => "321"
  ]
  [▼
    "singlePriceSummaryNetto" => "321,00"
  ]
  [▼
    "singleVat" => "23"
  ]
  [▼
    "singleVatSummary" => "73,83"
  ]
  [▼
    "singleSummaryBrutto" => "394,83"
  ]
]
```

I tried to do like that products[name][]
Output is: 
products

```
[▼
  "position" => [▼
    "1"
    "2"
  ]
  "name" => [▶]
  "quantity" => [▶]
  "singlePriceNetto" => [▶]
  "singlePriceSummaryNetto" => [▶]
  "singleVat" => [▶]
  "singleVatSummary" => [▶]
  "singleSummaryBrutto" => [▶]
]
```

Comment: Do you use php _

Comment: symfony but its matters ?

Answer (score 0):

Only provide index number to inputs and increment it works fine, if any another solutions to handle it, please free to answer.

Here is working example: `products[product][1][name]`